# System.NullReferenceException: "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json.net

Я хочу взять только id, medicareNumber и ogrn. Но говорит что: System.NullReferenceException: "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта."

WSDLTest.PracticeLocation.identification.get вернул null.

Что я делаю не так?

```
class PracticeLocation
{
    public Identification identification { get; set; }
}

class Identification
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int MedicareNumber { get; set; }
    public int Ogrn { get; set; }
}
```

```
PracticeLocation practiceLocation = JsonConvert
    .DeserializeObject<PracticeLocation>(result.RequestMessage);

Console.WriteLine(
    "Temperature in {0}: {1} C and {2}",  
    practiceLocation.identification.Id, 
    practiceLocation.identification.MedicareNumber, 
    practiceLocation.identification.Ogrn);`
```

`result.RequestMessage`:

```
{
   "practiceLocation":{
      "identification":{
         "id":"101",
         "medicareNumber":"101",
         "ogrn":"1681745",
         "okato":null,
         "okpo":null
      },
      "businessName":"Городская клиническая больница №1 г. . Поликлиника №1",
      "licence":{
         "licenceNumber":"ЛО-31-01-70",
         "licenceStartDate":"2019-02-08 00:00:00",
         "licenceEndDate":null,
         "licenceAdministrator":"Бюджетное учреждение"
      },
      "address":{
         "kladrCode":null,
         "addressText":" область, г. ,  проспект, 95а",
         "postalCode":"308"
      },
      "communicationNumbers":{
         "primaryTelephone":{
            "number":"+747222",
            "extension":null,
            "supportsSMS":null
         },
         "electronicMail":[
            
         ],
         "otherTelephone":[
            
         ]
      }
   },
   "softwareInformation":null
}
```

Comment: Так у вас в json PracticeLocation является вложенным, вам нужен корневой объект в котором будет свойство practiceLocation типа PracticeLocation

Answer (score 1):

Просто неправильно классы создал:

```
 public class Identification
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string medicareNumber { get; set; }
    public string ogrn { get; set; }
}

public class Licence
{
    public string licenceNumber { get; set; }
    public string licenceStartDate { get; set; }
    public object licenceEndDate { get; set; }
    public string licenceAdministrator { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public object kladrCode { get; set; }
    public string addressText { get; set; }
    public string postalCode { get; set; }
}

public class PrimaryTelephone
{
    public string number { get; set; }
    public object extension { get; set; }
    public object supportsSMS { get; set; }
}

public class CommunicationNumbers
{
    public PrimaryTelephone primaryTelephone { get; set; }
    public List<object> electronicMail { get; set; }
    public List<object> otherTelephone { get; set; }
}

public class PracticeLocation
{
    public Identification identification { get; set; }
    public string businessName { get; set; }
    public Licence licence { get; set; }
    public Address address { get; set; }
    public CommunicationNumbers communicationNumbers { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public PracticeLocation practiceLocation { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Названия свойств должны начинаться с заглавной буквы, так принято писать на `C#`. Следуйте стандартам, особенно если вы планируете в будущем зарабатывать себе на хлеб, нанимаясь в компании.